# How to get JSON Object data from Wikipedia URL

Tags: javascript, json, api

```
<script>
/*
{
      "batchcomplete": "",
      "query": {
        "pages": {
          "125293": {
            "pageid": 125293,
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "Copper",
            "revisions": [
              {
                "contentformat": "text\/x-wiki",
                "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                "*": "Some Data"
             }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
*/
var link ="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Copper&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json";
$.ajax({
    url: link,
    dataType: 'JSON',
    type: 'get',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).each(function(index, value) {
            //print value.child
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = value.query.pages.125293.title;
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Please provide me with and example on how to modify my code to get to the title child. Other alternatives are appreciated but please keep it simple. It seems that a lot of users just tend to copy and paste material from other site with not even a hint of how JQUERY works. So please don't paste some one else work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your code working ? What error do you have ?

Comment: if I print value only I get [object Object].

Comment: if I print value.item I get undefined and value.query.pages.125293.title gives me nothing.

Comment: i am using <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> at the header

Comment: remove `$(data).each(...)` - Use directly `data.value`

Comment: I did success: function(data) {

document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data.query.pages.125293.title;

} but nothing

Comment: What is inside data ?

Comment: document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = data.query.pages.125293[2].title;

Comment: Use `console.log(data)` to see what is inside

Comment: I used alert(data); and nothing.

Comment: Dude, this will be my last comment to help. If I am telling you to use `console.log(data)` it is for a reason. `alert(data)` won't display an object ! + be clearer when saying what happens : **nothing**..What does it mean ? An error ? undefined ? empty ?

Comment: ok I tested on jsbin and got an error on the console: "error" , "ReferenceError: '$' is undefined

Comment: hey thanks for the help, you may go then. No need for aggravations.

Comment: We are here to help you. If we are asking for more details - Please answer with more details. If we ask you do test something - test it, don't try to change it. `'$' is undefined` only means that you did not include jquery